# google map v3 is not fully displayed in html5

Tags: android, html, cordova, google-maps-api-3

google map v3 is not fully displayed in html5, phonegap.[image]

This map is drag-able, here is JavaScript code(main.js)

```
 var map;
 function initialize() {
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
 var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-24.363882,131.044922);

 var myOptions = {
 center: myLatlng,
 zoom:5,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
 myOptions);

 setMarker(myLatlng);
 setMarker(myLatlng2);

 }

 function setMarker(p)
 {
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: p,
 title:"Hello World 2!"
 });
 marker.setMap(map);

 }

 initialize();
```

and here is my html

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=yes;" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile.css" />
 <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/tabs.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.map/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.map/jquery.ui.map.services.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="page-id" data-role="page" >
 <div id="map-container"><div id="map_canvas" style="height:600px; width:600px;"></div>  </div>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

css

```
   #map-container {
    padding: 6px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
    width: 600px;
  }

  #map_canvas {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
  }
```

Please suggest me solution where is the problem if I inspect it in firebug it loads completely and show a complete map in div.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem and we solved it by setting "max-width: none" on the map . But I don't remember why. :(

Comment: let me try but where to add max-width in css of map-canvas? I tried #map_canvas {
        width: 100%;
  max-width:none;
        height: 100%;
      }     but doesn't make any difference

Comment: The code you posted has a specific height and width for the map_canvas div, the comment above you specify the height and width as percentage, which are you doing? The image you posted, is the classic symptom of a zero size  map div, which can easily occur if percentage size isn't done correctly.

Comment: should I change its height and width to percentage?

Comment: I changed it to percentage, I want it to in full div, either in specific height width or percentage

Comment: Try to specify an explicit width and height (in px) for both the map-container and the map_canvas divs. If it works you can then move onward.

Comment: #map_canvas {
        width: 300px;
  max-width:none;
        height: 300px;
      } ...........I dont know why nothing works here

Comment: I had the same problem.  The above solution does not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot it seems that the mapcontrol takes up the desired space but the actual map-area isn't large enough. Try to move your call to initialize(); so that it executes when the rest of the page has loaded and see if it helps.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-24.363882,131.044922);

  var myOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  setMarker(myLatlng);
  setMarker(myLatlng2);
}

function setMarker(p)
{
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: p,
    title:"Hello World 2!"
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  initialize();
});
```

Another solution might be to call the resize event and have the map control remeasure itself after everything has loaded, that is done by calling `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` (and call `initialize()` outside of the ready-function as before).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

Comment: Did you try the code you posted as a comment previously? I extended my sample a bit after seeing that one, not sure if the difference will help though. What system are you testing this on by the way?

Comment: I am testing in web browser and android simulator, in both it seems same. and yes I added both of your solutions in my code

Comment: let me try the second option to call initialize() outside the document ready

Comment: Nooo if I put it outside the document ready it does not work even stop showing map...Actually I had already document ready method and all js was inside that method.

Comment: me too also facing the same problem..If you found any solution plz help me out .

Comment: Facing same problem. Putting initialize in document ready does not even show the map. Only by putting it in $(document).on("pageinit", "#homepage", function() { ..  does the map show up.  But like other people, the map shows up great on first load. Once I navigate to some other page and come back, only half the map is seen and off towards the upper right.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check the following :

```
<div id="mapa"  style="width: 350px; height: 350px"></div>
```

Above is the div for map to be listed.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(
document.getElementById('mapa'), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.295680287227711, 76.87921151518822),
zoom: 8,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

I tried all the above wont work any so had done a trick like this which give desired result.
I write a mouse over function and call the below code

(1)  Modify

```
<div id="mapa" onmouseover="show_sidebar()" style="width: 350px; height: 350px"></div>
```

(2)

```
function show_sidebar(){
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue in the past and posted my solution to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059816/google-maps-v3-load-partially-on-top-left-corner-resize-event-does-not-work).

The following fixed it:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

Waiting for the map's idle state (i.e. it's finished loading itself) and then telling it to resize itself.